# How i can convert flp to iso file in correct way

Tags: assembly, operating-system

when i am converting virtual floppy disk to iso file it is not as it should be.
It has following problems:

1. It has lesser memory size.
2. It also not working when i tried to boot from it.

Is there any good method then please tell me. Sorry for poor language.

Answer (score 0):

if you are into Linux:
http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/floppy_image_on_cd.htm

What are you using to create the boot disk?
If you are just using windows and burning an .iso, try using the free software:
http://infrarecorder.org/
then burn it as a bootable disk.

Comment: i am on windwos..and using mkisofs.. it successfully create iso file but it has lesser size i am not getting why?